# Restricted visibility and search engine

Tags: 7, users, security

The search engine crawler, like Googlebot, doesn't index any data, which is set to be visible only particular user, right?

For example, let's say I have fields named field_A & field_B on user's fields, and also a permission named permission_X.

The field_A is set as "View own value for field" for user who has permission_X with Field Permissions module.
The field_B is set to be hidden on "Manage display", but is output through contextual filter set as "User id = User ID from logged in user" in Views.

If they're set so, do field_A & field_B still possibility to be indexed by Goolgebot?

I'm building development site with D7 now. And, I wonder if there will be a risk that the data, whose is visibility restricted, will be exposed through snippet or cached page in search result after I run the product site.

I'm afraid that this may be a very basic question but couldn't find any answer for it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Google can only index data it can see. If your data isn't available to anonymous users (which is how Google accesses your site), then it cannot index the data.

Comment: Thank you, Jaypan for your answer. Do you know whether there is any documentation written about what you wrote?

Comment: Not really, but there isn't really anything to write. Google accesses your site as an anonymous user. Google will index whatever it finds, unless told not to in robots.txt.